# GeoSpatial queries with Deployd

Tags: javascript, mongodb, geospatial

I am trying to get a geo-spatial setup running with [Deployd](http://deployd.github.com/deployd/).

On GET of something like this

```
/beam?{"loc": {"$near": [51,-114], "$limit": 10}}
```

I get an error

```
{
"message": "can't find special index: 2d for: { loc: { $near: [ 51, -114 ], $limit: 10 } }",
"status": 400
}
```

AFAIK, I need to put this
`foo.ensureIndex({loc:"2d", affiliation:1})` somewhere.

But Where? Where can I assign explicit indexes?

Comment: You only have to `ensureIndex()` once, just after your database table was created. You could do so just after connecting to the database as well.

Comment: Thanks. But I am using Deployd and hence I dont have explicit access to mongdb. Can you please tell me where do I use the ensureIndex() command?

Answer (score 1):

This question is over a year old, however, for those who are still figuring this out, do the following :

*collection / resource* = **beam**

*property / field* = **location**

Create a geo index on the **property** from mongodb shell -

```
db.*beam*.ensureIndex( { *location* : “2dsphere” } )
```

Add some geo data in **location** field -

```
{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -105, 39 ] }
```

Query it -

```
/resource_name?{"location":{"$near":{"$maxDistance":100000,"$geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-105,39]}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current version of deployd 0.6.9 does not seem to support index creation from dashboard, you must connect on mongodb with a [shell](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell) or if you use a mongodb provider like mongohq you can create spatial index on mongohq dashboard.